# Slicing array with numpy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

```
import numpy as np
r = np.arange(36)
r.resize((6, 6))

print(r)
# prints:
# [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
#  [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
#  [12 13 14 15 16 17]
#  [18 19 20 21 22 23]
#  [24 25 26 27 28 29]
#  [30 31 32 33 34 35]]

print(r[:,::7])
# prints:
# [[ 0]
#  [ 6]
#  [12]
#  [18]
#  [24]
#  [30]]

print(r[:,0])
# prints:
# [ 0  6 12 18 24 30]
```

The `r[:,::7]` gives me a column, the `r[:,0]` gives me a row, they both have the same numbers. Would be glad if someone could explain to me why?

Comment: Explain how `r[:,::7]` and `r[:,0]`  `have the same numbers`?

Comment: @Divakar Why shouldn't they contain the same numbers? The `r[:,::7]` is just `r[:, 0:6:7]` for an array of shape `(6, 6)`.

Comment: @MSeifert Ah yes! Just that the first one uses a range of indices, whereas the latter one uses a scalar for indexing. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: `r[:,[0]]`, `r[:,0:1]` also produce the column array. You get the 1d when indexing with a scalar; the other cases the result is 2d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the step argument is greater than the corresponding shape so you'll just get the first "row". However these are not identical (even if they contain the same numbers) because the scalar index in `[:, 0]` flattens the corresponding dimension (so you'll get a 1D array). But `[:, ::7]` will keep the number of dimensions intact but alters the shape of the step-sliced dimension.